# How to create generic class of type T, where T is Type variable?

Tags: flutter, dart, types

I'm trying to create list of generic typed class from mixed-type list.

It works, but the problem is each `Data` instance type is `dynamic`.

```dart
class Data<T> {
   final T value;

   const Data(this.value);
}

final List<dynamic> bases = [...];

final List<Data> data = bases.map((b) {
    return Data(b);
}).toList();
```

Attempt #2

```dart
class Data<T> {
   final T value;

   const Data(this.value);
}

final List<dynamic> bases = [...];

final List<Data> data = bases.map((b) {
    final Type T = b.runtimeType;
    return Data<T>(b);
}).toList(); // List<Data<dynamic>>
```

But it fails, due to: `The name 'T' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument. Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type parameters must be known *statically* (i.e., at compile-time).  If you start off with a heterogeneous `List<dynamic>`, then the static type of each element is `dynamic`, and therefore when you construct a `Data` object from that element, it will be `Data<dynamic>`.

If your heterogeneous list has a limited number of types, you could do:

```dart
var data = <Data<dynamic>>[];
for (var b in bases) {
  if (b is Foo) {
    var d = Data(b); // `d` is of type `Data<Foo>`
    data.add(d);
  } else if (b is Bar) {
    var d = Data(b); // `d` is of type `Data<Bar>`
    data.add(d);
  } else {
    throw UnimplementedError('Unrecognized type: ${b.runtimeType}');
  }
}
```

(Note that if you do `data.add(Data(b))` in the above, the `Data` object will be constructed as `Data<dynamic>` because the generic type parameter will be inferred from `data` (of type `List<Data<dynamic>>`) instead of from `b`.)

Otherwise what you want isn't really possible.